# Not able to redirect to another url in django python

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect to another url in django if the sessions are not created.
Here is my code of the function in views.py. It skips the redirect('/login') line. I want to redirect to the url temporarily, so that after login and it returns back to the same function.

```
def myfunction(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        client_id=request.GET['client_id']
        if 'member_id' not in request.session:
          redirect('/login')
        print "hello"
        #print request.session['member_id']
        m=client.objects.get(id=client_id)
    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) function:

`return redirect('/login')` should work.

Comment: Thanks!! But i am facing another problem. If the sessions are not created, it goes to login page and user logs in and sessions are created. But in that case i have to return HttpResponse Object and it doesn't resume where it had left earlier

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, the line should be:

```
if 'member_id' not in request.session:
    return redirect('/login')
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect

However, your specific statement was that the line wasn't executing. If that's the case, then print out `reqeust.session` before the `if` statement to see if `'member_id'` is in it or not.

You also have a small formatting error on the `redirect` line (not enough whitespace).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it answers the `It skips the redirect('/login') line.` portion of the question as well.